# how to display multiple divs on a side and one div on other side?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I multiple divisions on the left side but when i place a single division on the right side, It shows up on the next line. I want a `sidebar` so I want `sidebar div` on the right side of the box. `float right` makes it appear on the right side of the box but not beside the other `divs`.

[JSFiddle Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/sdq6meyx/2/)

Comment: Can you simplify your code? It's a little hard to understand what are trying to do. Just use let's say some `div`s with text.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/sdq6meyx/2/

Comment: I have removed the code and added simply divs instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the div `f` to appear to the right of all the others. The others are all contained within the div `a`.

Unfortunately, `f` is also contained within `a`, which I think is part of what is giving you the problem.

If you move `f` outside of `a`, and float both `a` and `f` *left* then in a wide-enough layout they will appear side-by side. If the display is not wide enough for this (e.g. on a mobile device) then `f` will automatically slide underneath `a`.

All the other divs are contained within `a` and are not directly affected.

HTML:

```
<div class ="a">
  <div class ="b">
  </div>
  <div class ="c">
  </div>
  <div class ="d">
  </div >
  <div class ="e">
  </div>
</div>
<div class ="f">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   float: left;
 }

 .b {
   background-color: red;
   width: 330px;
   height: 50px;
 }

 .c {
   background-color: aqua;
   width: 300px;
   height: 60px;
 }

 .d {
   background-color: cadetblue;
   width: 320px;
   height: 70px;
 }

 .e {
   background-color: black;
   width: 200px;
   height: 20px;
 }

 .f {
   background-color: pink;
   width: 70px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
 }
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/sdq6meyx/5/ for a demo

Answer (score 0):

You can assign`float: right` to that element (`.f`)  as you wrote, but in the HTML code you'll have to place it as the first elemente inside the `.a` div, above all the other elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/z4hhox53/2/

Comment: But I need it inside the blue `div` since that is the main `div` that holds all the other ones. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Ah okay. I just changed my answer and the fiddle: Just place it into the `.a` div, above the other elements in there